# Clipped Corner Div with a Separate Linear Gradient

Tags: css, background, gradient

Instead of falling back on SVG, I'd love to accomplish this with pure CSS.

There are a number of tutorials on clipped edges using a series of Linear Gradients, i.e.

```
background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 15px, blue 0) top left,
            linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 15px, blue 0) top right,
            linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 15px, blue 0) bottom right,
            linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 15px, blue0) bottom left;
background-size: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

And a diagonal "linear gradient" can also be accomplished quite easily, i.e.

```
background: linear-gradient(290deg, blue 50%, darkblue 50%);
```

Is there a way to combine these two techniques to get something like the box pictured below?

[image]

Edit: Internet Explorer compatibility would be great.

```
-webkit-clip-path
clip-path
```

Are not IE compatible to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can define one transparent corner via background gradient. However, when you declare more than one, they paint over the transparency defined by the previous rule. In essence, they paint over each other.

A better solution is to use [`clip-path`](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path). For simple shapes, you can use [clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

#gradients {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0) top left, linear-gradient(-135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0) top right, linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0) bottom right, linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15px, blue) bottom left;
}

#gradientsPaintover {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15px, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4) 0) top left, linear-gradient(-135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15px, rgba(0, 0, 255, 1) 0) top right;
}


#clip {
  background: red;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 80% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 80%, 0% 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 80% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 80%, 0% 20%);
}
```

```html
<div id="gradients"></div>
<div id="gradientsPaintover"></div>
<div id="clip"></div>
```

Comment: This works well in everything but internet explorer. Any solutions that will support that? I will edit the original question.

Comment: @TimWillis imo, this is so cosmetic that it doesn't ruin the experience all that much. You don't want SVG, but you want 100% browser support...something's got to give.

Comment: Thank you @SergChernata! I added an answer that is a more complete response and I appreciate your help. I upvoted your answer but I don't have much clout yet.

Answer (score 0):

Serg's answer was helpful in solving the problem, but I thought'd I'd post a complete solution.

```
background: linear-gradient(290deg, blue 50%, darkblue 50%);
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 95% 0, 100% 10%, 100% 90%, 95% 100%, 5% 100%, 0 90%, 0 10%);
clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 95% 0, 100% 10%, 100% 90%, 95% 100%, 5% 100%, 0 90%, 0 10%);
```

A note that this will not work at all in IE and you should pursue the SVG option in that case.

Edit: spending some more time with this, there's no reason you couldn't create pseudo elements before and after your `div` that contains a `linear-gradient` to add the 'cut edge' look.

See [codepen here](https://codepen.io/t1mwillis/pen/GXaOwr) or CSS below.

```
/*div and interior BG*/
div {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px; /*Make sure your content has a height specified*/
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(290deg, blue 50%, darkblue 50%);
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

/*Shared styles across pseudo elements*/
div:before, div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 300px; /*Fits psuedo element height to content*/
  position: absolute;
  display:inline-block;
}
/*Position and cuts for left side*/
div:before {
  left: -9.9%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 15px, darkblue 0) top left,
            linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 15px, darkblue 0) bottom left;
  background-size: 100% 51%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/*Position and cuts for left right*/
div:after {
  right: -9.9%;
  background:
            linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 15px, blue 0) top right,
            linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 15px, blue 0) bottom right;
  background-size: 100% 51%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```